# Медленная загрузка страниц. Проблема с MYSQL запросами или что-то другое?

Tags: php, mysql

Ранее, мне подсказали, что основной проблемой медленной загрузки страниц являются медленные mysql-запросы.

Я начал  анализировать все запросы и у меня возник вопрос : Почему у меня запрос, выполненный сайтом (создал страницу с этим запросом), занимает примерно 2 секунды, но если этот запрос я вбиваю вручную в через **phpmyadmin** , то там он выполняется за 0.2 секунды  ?

Получается, проблема не с MYSQL ?

Comment: Получается проблема не с MYSQL)

Comment: "основной проблемой медленной загрузки страниц являются медленные mysql-запросы." --- основной проблемой, но не 100% постоянной)) проблема может быть например в PHP при использовании ActiveRecord моделей например.....в плохом медленном коде. так что копать надо во многие стороны, а не только в БД.

Comment: Время на исполнение страницы с запросом - это не только время самого запроса. вы можете вызвать microtime до и после - и получить время на запрос. а дальше так же попрофилировать остальные части кода. Но возможно, у вас просто страница столько времени грузится. 0.2 - это же время которое, вам phpadmin показывает